# opensource tool for Oracle Change data capture - Alternative to GoldenGate

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, change-data-capture

Looking for an Open source alternative to GoldenGate that will stream all the DML operation in the source Oracle to a compacted kafka topic. My employer acknowledge that Larry doesn't possibly need another island. So licensing Oracle GoldenGate is not an option.

Looked at https://gitter.im/linkedin/brooklin, https://github.com/linkedin/databus , https://github.com/debezium/debezium so far. I couldn't find any documentation that states how to do Oracle CDC using these. Any pointer will be greatly appreciated. I am not asking any opinions or recommendations, I am seeking viable alternatives of GoldenGate.

### Edit

I got this from Debezium [gitter](https://gitter.im/debezium/user)/slack channel, https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/oracle/. But this still needs GoldenGate license.

Comment: You might not be asking for recommendations, but *asking for a tool/off-site resource* ***is*** considered off-topic.

Comment: See also: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/283350/how-can-i-get-all-data-from-a-given-table-since-my-last-run

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are all your options: https://rmoff.net/2018/12/12/streaming-data-from-oracle-into-kafka-december-2018/

It's worth noting there are cheaper commercial alternatives to GoldenGate, so your choice is not purely between open source and GoldenGate only.

Comment: Thanks.. this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

There is a new project called [OpenLogReplicator](https://github.com/bersler/OpenLogReplicator). It can be found on GitHub. The project has version 1.0 released and there are companies using it on production. At this moment this is the only open source Redo Log reader available.